# How do I print the application's path?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

How do I print the application's path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSLog( @"%@" , [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] );
```

Comment: Thanks but how does one find this in the apple documentation?

Comment: **Swift**: `print(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)`